# Text selection bug with draft.js and decorator

Tags: javascript, draftjs

I'm using a draft.js editor in such a way that I need to update the decorator and also the props of the component it renders on the fly inside `onChange`. This to mark parts of the text with a background color.

I can almost get this working, but there's a weird bug where among other things it is not possible to select the character immediately after one of the decorated components.

Here is a minimal (artificial) example to reproduce the bug:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CompositeDecorator, Editor, EditorState } from 'draft-js';


const Marked = ({ children, background }) => <span style={{ background }}>{children}</span>;


class TestEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(editorState) {
    const markers = [{ from: 3, to: 7 }, { from: 12, to: 15 }];

    const strategy = (contentBlock, callback) => {
      const text = contentBlock.getText();
      markers.forEach(({ from, to }) => {
        if (text.length >= to) callback(from, to);
      });
    };

    const decorator = new CompositeDecorator([
      { strategy, component: (props) => <Marked {...props} background="#00ff2a1a" /> },
    ]);

    const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, { decorator });

    this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState });
  }

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;

    return <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
}

export default TestEditor;
```

This will be a text input where the text at position 3 - 7 and 12 - 15 has a green background (if it exists).

If I now for example write `aaabbbbccc` it is not possible to select the first `c`. Using the mouse it is selected until I release the mouse button; using the keyboard it doesn't appear to be selected at all (it might be momentarily).

If I use a static component with no new input in the `handleChange` method it works ok: `const decorator = new CompositeDecorator([{ strategy, component: Marked }]);`. However this doesn't fit my use case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: little can do 'on the fly'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turns out I can do what I need with draft's `entities`, probably with much better performance