# draft-js bug with selection if decorator at end of content-block

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am building an extended editor based on draft-js to add a footnote feature. When writing text in the main editor, the user has the option to click "add footnote", which adds a footnotemark (a badge with the number of the note) at the current selection, and opens a secondary editor where to write the text of the note.

It all works well, except that if you add a note at the very **end of a content-block**, it is **impossible to place the cursor after** the footnotemark to keep writing after it.

A note consists in an `entity` with length 1 at the position of the footnotemark, which is a character "N" on which we superpose a `Chip` which is a `CompositeDecorator`.

I have reproduced the problem in a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-selection-decorator-draft-js-nyc2f?file=/src/ExtendedEditor.js), which is focused only on the markers (there is no problem with the text content of the notes).
Try writing some text and adding a footnotemark at the very end, it is impossible to place the selection after the footnotemark and keep writing, which is note the case if you place the footnotemark before the end of the text.

Any help will be greatly appreciated !!

I saw that jorgen posted a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716719/text-selection-bug-with-draft-js-and-decorator) with a quite similar problem but I could not find a relevant answer there .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't ask me why, but when you [don't render the children](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/390#issuecomment-219530350) in your decorator component weird things happen

this little change solve your problem

```js
const NoteChip = ({ entityKey, contentState, children }) => (
  <Badge
    contentEditable={false}
    badgeContent={"N"}
    color="primary"
    id={"note-chip-" + entityKey}
    style={{ marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 5, cursor: "pointer", top: 5 }}
  >
    <span>{children}</span>
  </Badge>
);

...
  // insert a blank space instead of the N
  contentState = Modifier.insertText(
    contentState,
    newSelection(blockKey, offset),
    " "
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-selection-decorator-draft-js-forked-dzuxl

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer, really helped. 
Just the cursor now goes to the right-end of the editor, any idea why ?

Comment: @LucasDavid I don't understand your new issue, It works fine for me, when clicking the add footnotemark button it puts the badge in the cursor position and then I click back on the input and I'm able to move the cursor to the right end, maybe you can make a gif or video of what you mean

Comment: If 1. you write some text, 2. add fotenotemark at the end and 3., click in the editor, the cursor goes to the right-end of the editor
See example in [this gif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VJCb77s25li-a04BcUiwzsYajSZsMtyB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @LucasDavid that's weird, it doesn't happen to me, what browser + version are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome 85.0.4183.121 but it is the same in Safari 14.0 ... Maybe our codes are still different, I just modified 2 thinks as you suggested : rendering children in `NoteChip` and inserting a blank space instead of "N" in `addFootNoteMark`

Comment: @LucasDavid I added the link to the codesandbox I used

Comment: Perfect thanks !! Still don't get why I had this issue but now it seems fixed.